# javafx создать menu и реализовать кнопки в нем

Tags: java, javafx

Как в этом новом окне добавить меню?. Спасибо!

```
FXMLLoader cwidow = new FXMLLoader();
cwidow.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/AutWindow.fxml"));

        try {
            cwidow.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Parent croot = cwidow.getRoot();
        Stage cstage = new Stage();
        cstage.setScene(new Scene(croot));
        cstage.setTitle("my app");
        cstage.setResizable(false);
        cstage.show();

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Сначала создается `MenuBar`, затем в него добавляется `Menu`, и затем в него - пункты меню `MenuItem`.

Сам `MenuBar` вставляется в тот элемент, где должно быть меню:

- В FXML (можно и в Scene Builder):

  ```
  <BorderPane>
    <top>
      <MenuBar>
        <Menu text="File">
          <MenuItem text="Exit" />
        </Menu>
      </MenuBar>
    </top>
  </BorderPane>
  ```
- То же самое - кодом (здесь, для примера, предполагается, что корневой элемент в .fxml-файле - это BorderPane):

  ```
  MenuItem exitMenuItem = new MenuItem("Exit");

  Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");
  fileMenu.getItems().add(exitMenuItem);

  MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
  menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);

  BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane)root;
  borderPane.setTop(menuBar);
  ```

Comment: это понятно. но так MenuBar не добавляется текущую окно а в новом окне, нада в текущем Anchor pane добавить!

Comment: `((AnchorPane)croot).getChildren().add(menuBar);` -- Вы об этом спрашивали?